# How to create a new file of the same name every time it runs

Tags: java

I have a Folder inbox, now every time a user chooses to send a mail, it creates a new file in inbox. Now my code, creates only one file for all mails. I thought of making a counter but that will just reset to zero every time it runs.

```
int mailCounter = 0;
String mailPath = ""+"Server\\"+rcptEmail+"\\Inbox\\Mail"+mailCounter;
File Mail = new File(mailPath);
mailCounter++;
                            
 try{
      if(Mail.createNewFile()){
             System.out.println("Mail created");
      } 
 }catch(Exception error){}
```

Any ideas on how to make it such as

- Inbox

  - Mail1
  - Mail2
  - Mail3

Comment: You either need to store the file number in a settings file somewhere, or scan the folder, find the file with the highest number, then use that +1.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908985/how-to-create-a-new-file-of-the-same-name-every-time-it-runs#comment116532575_65908985) to your question, i.e. list the files in folder `Inbox` and get the largest number. Then add 1 (one) to it and create a new file whose name is `Mail` plus the number.

The below code simply shows how to get the largest number. I presume you can figure out the rest. Note that the code uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ListFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mailPath = ""+"Server\\"+rcptEmail+"\\Inbox";
        Path dir = Paths.get(mailPath);
        try {
            Optional<Integer> maybeMax = Files.list(dir)
                                              .map(path -> path.getFileName().toString())
                                              .filter(name -> name.startsWith("Mail"))
                                              .map(path -> Integer.valueOf(path.substring(4)))
                                              .sorted()
                                              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
            int max = maybeMax.orElse(Integer.valueOf(0));
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Create a stream of all the files in folder `Inbox`.
2. Filter out all the files whose name does not start with `Mail`.
3. Get the number at the end of the file name.
4. Sort the numbers.
5. Get the largest number.